proton failing to connect to audio system
My audio works fine so far for everything including non-steam games and native steam games.
when I check the logs I get:
ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Timeout
that happens twice and before each it waits for what seems like 10 seconds.
I use pipewire/wireplumber/pipewire-pulse running without --user since I need multiple users to be able to output at once to the same device.
It's the same on x and wayland.
I tried doing protontricks <app_id> winecfg
and I can go to the audio tab and see my devices and play sounds but it doesn't work when i run it through steam?
edit: running on of the games (noita) through lutris produced the same error
